# What is the reference for the following from Bhagavad geeta?

Tags: identification-request

Which sloka in bhagavad gita says:

> Arjuna: How do I know that it is Dharma, O Keshava?
>   
> Krishna: When the Adharmic lament, know that Dharma has manifested.

Comment: These verses are not in the bg.

Comment: not in B. Gita.

Answer (score 3):

The line *nowhere* appears in Bhagavad Gita. Not even the Mahabharata. You might have found this on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/OGSaffron/status/1131489333951832064?s=20) or Reddit post which was extensively shared with a picture of Krishna and Arjuna.

Actually, Arjuna asks the following question to Krishna. The closest I found:

> kārpaṇya doṣopahata svabhāvaḥ pṛcchāmi **tvāṁ dharma samūḍha cetasaḥ** |
>   yacchreyaḥ syān niścitaṁ brūhi tan me śiṣyas te śādhi māṁ tvāṁ prapannam || 7 ||
>
> Now **I am confused about my duty** and have lost all composure because of miserly weakness. In this condition I am asking You to tell me for certain what is best for me. Now I am Your disciple, and a soul surrendered unto You. Please instruct me.

But Krishna doesn't talk about Adharmics and their lamentation. He starts his preaching of Bhagavad Gita.

> aśocyān anvaśocas tvaṁ prajñāvādāṁśca bhāṣase |
>   gatāsūn agatāsūṁśca nānuśocanti paṇḍitāḥ || 11 ||
>
> The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: While speaking learned words, you are mourning for what is not worthy of grief. Those who are wise lament neither for the living nor for the dead.

Translations from the site [bhagavad-gita.us](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/).

This is another wrongly attributed quote to the Bhagavad Gita and conversation between Krishna and Arjuna.